# Spring security with vaadin combined with thymeleaf

Tags: spring-security, vaadin

The spring security annotations are ignored on the Vaadin views; I have a @DenyAll at the class level but the view is rendered anyway.

The project combines thymeleaf and vaadin within spring boot. The first for a fast rendering of a large HTML with command and events over a websocket, the latter for ease of developing the administrative screens. Vaadin is setup under "/vdn/", spring MVC with thymeleaf under "/".

Spring security works correctly in thymeleaf; login, logout, and the sec:authorize correctly hides or shows parts of the generated HTML. But the security tag on the Vaadin view is ignored.

```
@Route("/")
@StyleSheet("context://../vaadin.css")
@DenyAll
public class MainView extends AppLayout  {
```

Based on the documentation (https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/security/enabling-security) if no annotation is present the view should not be shown at all, it however is. So somehow Vaadin is not picking up the Spring security. Any suggestions what is missing?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity 
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder()) //
            .dataSource(dataSource) //
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, enabled from person where username=?") //
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role from person where username=?") //
        ;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests() //
            .anyRequest().authenticated() //
            .and() //
            .formLogin() //
            .and() //
            .csrf().disable() // needed for vaadin https://tutorialmeta.com/question/server-connection-lost-after-successful-login-with-spring-security
            .logout() 
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
        ;
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you rolling your own security configuration or extending VaadinWebSecurity?

Comment: Please share the security setup (the code, not the prose).

Comment: Added. I'm not using the deprecated approach which extends spring's WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. The VaadinWebSecurity class is not available. But to be frank, I do not understand Vaadin's documentation. Why is the userDetailsService needed if JDBC authentication is setup? The documentation is not matching my setup.

Comment: VaadinWebSecurity is only available in 23.2+

Comment: Your code has no Vaadin related security customization in place, so it's impossible for the view based security to work. See https://github.com/vaadin/flow/blob/814373deb17d9ec914e1da69030b6c8b8deae60c/vaadin-spring/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/spring/security/VaadinWebSecurity.java#L177 how you can enable view based access checks.

Comment: Ah! I had 23.1.2... Now I can extend the correct class. The documentation really is fuzzy, because the example code may extend the class, but it uses the old way of configuring (@Override instead of @Bean). And I cannot call the super.configure from the @Bean method. "Can't configure anyRequest after itself" Compared to the code above I added the "extends VaadinWebSecurity" (which is not enough to active the annotations) and "super.configure(http)

Comment: @tbeernot as the 23.2.0 was a minor release, it tries to minimize the impact of upgrading to it. Behind the scene, it uses the `@Bean` style to do the configurations, but most of the existing users upgrading to this version are appreciating the existence of the same methods and signatures and do not except a breaking change semantically. For other problems, please refer to my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments as well, in order for the Vaadin View-Based security to work, it should be enabled first by extending your security configuration class from `VaadinWebSecurity` (for V23.2+) or `VaadinWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` (older versions). You can refer to the documentation here: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/security/enabling-security/#security-configuration-class

When extending from either of the above classes, if you are overriding the `void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception` method (which is needed almost always), do not forget to call `super.configure(http);` in the correct order mentioned that mentioned in the documentation. This is important as the `viewAccessChecker` bean is enabled through this call, and this is what you need to have the View-Based security work.

**Note:** You probably have seen the chain of calls on `http.authorizeRequests()` (which is of type `ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry`) in many tutorials and documentations. Once the `.anyRequest().PermitAll()` or some similar method is called on it, it does not accept any more configuration of those pattern matching configurations, so **it is important to configure your custom pattern matching configs before the call to** `super.configure(http);` (as shown in the mentioned documentation).

Finally, setting the login form which is done in the documentation via calling `setLoginView(http, LoginView.class);` is an important step, as not only does it introduce your custom login view to the `viewAccessChecker` bean, but, it also enables Spring Security's form-based login feature which is needed for the view-based security mechanism to work properly.

If you have all the steps mentioned above in order, then those access annotations such as `@DenyAll` or `@RolesAllowed` are taken into account and you can expect them to work as documented. If you still have problems enabling it, please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that isolates your problem so that the community can help more effectively.

Comment: The essence was that I needed to remove anyRequest().authenticated() from the configuration and replace it with antMatcher("**").authenticated(). Then it could be forwarded to super.configuration(http). In that setup it does not matter if you use the old Override or the new Bean approach. I went for the last. So this answer is not directly solving the problem, but it did put me on the right track with the anyRequest() remark.